# How to create a common matching text string for a set of two text code blocks in the opposite order

Tags: excel

For a data set I have two columns, one for the origin code and one for the destination, and I need to combine codes with a matching set in the opposite order into one common set.

I've tried several different concat methods as well as trying to assign a unique value to each combination but can never manage to unpack the code sets that mirror each other.

Example of desired outcome in column D (no particular order preference as long as they're combined and consistent across combinations):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple `COUNTIF` should work here:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(D$1:D1,C2&B2),C2&B2,B2&C2)
```

[image]